# Access Array inside Array $scope Children inside Parent Database ( NODE Angular MongoDB Javascript )

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am running this codes in my NODE app:

Controller

```
Shirts.get({ shirtId: $stateParams.shirtId, cat: $stateParams.cat },function(response){
        $scope.Beta = response;
});
```

view

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="sh in Beta">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="sh.category[0]._id" id="name" >
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="sh.category[0].name" id="name">
</ul>
```

The previous code is working just fine

Response:

556ab2a4789bf9769ea813e3

aa

But When I change it to the following it does not work

Controller

```
Shirts.get({ shirtId: $stateParams.shirtId, cat: $stateParams.cat },function(response){
            $scope.Beta = response.category[0];
});
```

View

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="sh in Beta">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="sh.name" id="name" >
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="sh._id" id="name" >
</ul>
```

Error says that :
 Cannot read property '0' of undefined

It seems like it cannot find category but I do have a category.
Here is what I have in my Console ( Which is the same as Response from controller ):

```
{ _id: 556ab2a4789bf9769ea813e0, category: [ { name: 'aa', _id: 556ab2a4789bf9769ea813e3, picture: [] } ] }
```

How can I access array inside array in $scope?

Thanks

Comment: you mean the response I receive from the first code?

Comment: response is an array, isn't it? With `ng-repeat="sh in Beta"` you iterate over that array.

Comment: Yes What I have in Console is response !

Comment: @SaeedNode.js so what exactly you have in response Array or Object?

Comment: well, regarding your code examples and error you've got it seems like an Array, just try `$scope.Beta = response[0].category;`

Comment: Thank you
It works!
But Why I need [0] after response and why it is not necessary for the first code?

Comment: in first code ngRepeate loop by response, so `sh` inside - is something like `response[0]` and etc